# Pymc MAP - How to extract the final values?

Tags: python, pymc

I have a pretty big model that I fit with `pymc.MAP`:

```
M = pymc.MAP(model)
M.fit(iterlim=1000)
```

where `model` is a large list containing many pymc objects which works fine in an MCMC sampler. However, my problem is that when I try to fit the above MAP, I don't know how to extract the results. The model is pretty big so I'm not going to post the whole file, but for example, it definitely contains:

```
arctanA = np.empty(numbins, dtype=object)
C = np.empty(numbins, dtype=object)
for i in range(numbins):
    arctanA[i] = pymc.Uniform('arctanA_%i' %i, -math.pi/2, math.pi/2)
    C[i] = pymc.Uniform('C_%i' %i, 0, 2)
```

However, when I try to extract the above values with `M.C.value` or `M.C_0.value`, it gives me an `AttributeError: 'MAP' object has no attribute 'C_0'` and so on. So what am I doing wrong here? Is there some special way that I need to define the objects to extract them later?

Answer (score 0):

The optimal values are in the elements of the collections of variables you have specified. Try `C[0].value`, for example.